# jQuery getting sum with keypress always one step behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to create an calculator in which I want add/sum on every key press I make like this:

```
$('#padd').keypress(function() {

    var ypoints = "200";        
    var points = parseInt( $(this).val() );

    console.log( "Points: " + (points + parseInt(ypoints)) );

});
```

My issue is that it seems like "points" always is one step behind. Lets say that my "ypoints" is 200 and I type in first 1, the console.log says "NaN"? If I then type in a "10" the console.log says "201" while in fact it should say "210"?!? If I then add an "100" in the add field it says "210" but it should say "300". Always one keypress behind?!?

What am I missing here or is this not the correct way to do this?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Use keyup event, keypress is triggred before the value is assigned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try using the `keyup` function instead](http://jsbin.com/hezijavuyo/2/edit) (although you might not want to listen for `key*` events at all, see below):

```
$('#padd').keyup(function(){
  var ypoints = 200;        
  var points = parseInt($(this).val());
  console.log("Points: "+(points+ypoints));
});
```

Instead of `keyup`, you should [listen for the explicit `input` event](http://jsbin.com/xidilebemo/3/edit):

```
$('#padd').on("input", function(){
  var ypoints = 200;        
  var points = parseInt($(this).val());
  console.log("Points: "+(points+ypoints));
});
```

An example when listening for the `input` event trumps using `keyup` is when [using an `input` of type `number`](http://jsbin.com/retoyonedu/2/edit). In a [(not so) modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number), this adds a stepper to the input field, which you can use to increment or decrement the inputs value by 1 using your mouse. This does not fire the `keyup` event (no keys are pressed) but nevertheless changes the value.

---

It is really a matter of when certain events are fired and the state of the `input`'s value at that time. There is an [explanation on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html):

> **keyup**
>
> Fires when the user releases a key, **after** the default action of that key has been performed.

and more information on the `input` event on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an  or  element is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its a working code : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhans/cnfbvqh7/)

```
$('#padd').keyup(function(){
        var ypoints = "200";        
        var points = parseInt($(this).val());
        alert("Points: "+(points+parseInt(ypoints)));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Problem in ParseInt function.
  try this Code:

    $('#padd').keypress(function(){

    var ypoints = "200";        
    var points = parseInt($(this).val());

    console.log("Points: "+parseInt(ypoints+points));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also code this way...

```
    function GetTextboxAmount(obj) {

        var retVal = 0;

        try {
            if (obj.val() == "") {
                retVal = 0;
            } else if (obj.val() == '') {
                retVal = 0;
            } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(obj.val()))) {
                retVal = 0;
            } else {
                retVal = Math.round(parseFloat(obj.val()));
            }

        } catch (e) { retVal = 0; }
        obj.val(retVal);
        return retVal;
    }

$('#padd').keyup(function(){

    var ypoints = "200";        
    var points = GetTextboxAmount($(this));

    console.log("Points: "+(points+parseInt(ypoints)));

});
```